# VBA - difference between returning array with or without parenthesis in function

Tags: arrays, vba, function, return, difference

Why does `getArray = returnArray` and `getArray = returnArray()` give the same result?

I thought `getArray = returnArray()` would call the `returnArray` sub, but this isn't the case.

```
Sub returnArray()
    MsgBox "doesn't print"
End Sub

Function getArray() As Integer()
    Dim returnArray(1) As Integer
    
    returnArray(0) = 22
    returnArray(1) = 6
    
    getArray = returnArray
    'getArray = returnArray() gives the same result
    
End Function

Sub question()

    Dim arr() As Integer
    
    arr = getArray()
    
    MsgBox arr(1)
      
End Sub
```

Comment: calling a sub the same name as a declared array will not call the sub when the array variable is referred to.  They are two different things and by using the same name can cause issues in the sub when Excel guesses what you want.  But if you put just `returnArray` in the last sub it will call it.

Comment: One can't assign a `Sub` to anything btw, that'll be a Compile error.

Comment: Not positive on this but at a guess returning `returnArray` returns a variant whereas `returnArray()` returns an actual array, in your case an integer array.